# Control activity from a service

Tags: java, android

I'm coding an Android app, and I have to use websockets… I use 2 activities and a service: I use my main activity to take information on server, and I use a service to connect to this server. I want from this service to start the other activity, or let know to my main activity, when to start the other one. How can I do that ?
Thanks for helping

Comment: You can start that activity from the service just like in activity!

Comment: @Mistercraft You can try my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this .

**1.You must add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` for your `Intent` .**

Else,you you will has

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

**2.You can use `intent.putExtra("key","value");` to pass data like `Activity`**

**Sample**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
// add flags
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(intent);
```